# Android: how do I hide SearchView icon if RecyclerView is empty?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, menuitem

I have a `RecyclerView` with two possible `Views`.  The first `View` loads a default layout called `emptyView`.  The second `View` replaces the first `View` when the user creates a new `CardView`.  I am looking to add search capability to the `RecyclerView`.

I would like to not show the `action_search` icon on the `AppBar` when the `RecyclerView` is empty; that is, before any `CardViews` are created.  After the user creates a `CardView` then I would like the `action_search` icon to appear on the `AppBar`.  So how can I link the `SearchView` code and the `setOnActionExpandListener` for the Search function to hide the search icon for the first view?  Then after a `CardView` is created, recognize that the `emptyView !=null` and the `RecyclerViewAdapter !=null` to show the second view?

**Activity.java**

```
...  

// setEmptyView() in the EmptyRecyclerView subclass, calls checkIfEmpty()
// empty_view is an empty view (Linear Layout) that is shown when the 
// RecyclerView is empty (the default case).
   recyclerView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty_view)); 
...
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {        
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cardview_menu, menu);
    final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(item,
        new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                return true;
            }
        });
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

EmptyRecyclerView.java
...
public class EmptyRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {

private View emptyView;
...
void checkIfEmpty() {
    if (emptyView != null && getAdapter() != null) {
        final boolean emptyViewVisible =
                getAdapter().getItemCount() == 0;
        emptyView.setVisibility(emptyViewVisible ? VISIBLE : GONE);
        setVisibility(emptyViewVisible ? GONE : VISIBLE);
    }

    public void setEmptyView(View emptyView) {
    this.emptyView = emptyView;
    checkIfEmpty();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 

if (getAdapter() == null || getAdapter().getItemCount() == 0) {
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cardview_menu, menu);
final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(item,
    new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            return true;
        }
    });
return true;
}
```

When your card view is created, then after setting data in recyclerView just call `invalidateOptionsMenu();`

**UPDATE:**

If there are multiple items in your menu list and you have to hide/show only one of them:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 

getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cardview_menu, menu);
final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

if (getAdapter() == null || getAdapter().getItemCount() == 0) {
    item.setVisible(false);
}else {
    item.setVisible(true);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
}
MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(item,
    new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            return true;
        }
    });
return true;
}
```

Comment: The invalidateOptionsMenu() redraws the menu view since the menu was changed?

Comment: Yeah, it will call onCreateOptionsMenu and in this method, you have a check that inflates menu items only when there is something in recyclerView.

Comment: Ok I understand.  Would using boolean isVisible() on the menu item be more efficient?  I don't know whether that or your approach would use less system resources.

Comment: isVisible() for what?

Comment: android doc says abstract boolean isVisible() returns the visibility of the menu item.

Comment: I think you have to check on the basis of data in your recyclerView rather the previous visibility of menu items. Try, if it works then it's good.

Comment: Got it, I will give it a try.

Comment: One problem, this hides the other action items on the menu which is the "Add Item" icon (so I am not able to create a CardView) and the Overflow icon.  Any thoughts on how to fix?

Comment: Ok the action_search icon is hidden at first so that is working correctly.  But when a CardView is created and the UI view is updated the search icon is not appearing.  So it seems like "item.setVisible(true) is not working.  I tried with and without "invalidateOptionsMenu()" and neither worked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133240/discussion-between-charu-and-ajw).

Comment: Had to run invalidateOptionsMenu() for each case when the Adapter is updated to reflect zero items (a null list or size ==0) and one or more items (to reflect a list with size >0).